# Error extracting a RAR archive: "is not RAR archive.No files to extract"

Tags: linux, archive, rar

I have multiple huge RAR files that are separated into 6 parts.Some parts are completely downloaded,some not just yet.When I try to extract the fully downloaded archives,I get this:

```
$ unrar e whatever.rar
...
whatever.rar is not RAR archive
No files to extract
```

BTW `x` and even `t` switches don't work for me.The interesting fact is that the `l` switch can successfully list the contents:

```
$ unrar l whatever.rar

Archive: whatever.rar
Details: RAR 4, volume, recovery record, lock

 Attributes      Size     Date    Time   Name
----------- ---------  ---------- -----  ----
*   ..A.... 2097555771  2015-02-23 11:07  whatever/1
*   ..A.... 2097957006  2015-02-23 11:09  whatever/2
*   ..A.... 2097895618  2015-02-23 11:09  whatever/3
----------- ---------  ---------- -----  ----
           4195852624  volume 3          2
```

I've tried that using **Ark**.It says:

```
Loading the archive ‘whatever.rar’ failed with the following error:
Failed to find all archive volumes
```

Can it be because of the fact that not of all the archives(i.e parts) has been downloaded yet?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It might be a corrupted archive.

Comment: @annahri So why the ```t``` switch doesn't work to tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The [`rar` man page](https://ss64.com/bash/rar.html) documents a switch called `-en`, which has this note: 'This switch cannot be used with volumes, **because the end of archive block contains information important for correct volume processing**'. You've mentioned explicitly that you don't have all the parts yet, so this may be the cause of your issue. Can you try again once you have all the parts, and see if the issue disappears?

Comment: Thanks @Haxiel.Currently my internet connection is quite limited,so no possibility to check that for now.But when it gets completed,should I decompress all of them at once?Like ```unrar x 1.rar 2.rar ...```?